# Getting an integer to go to a different line

Tags: java, system.out

This is my code for reversing the digits of an integer,
but the result gives each digit reversed but in a new line,
like if you give 341 to it , it gives you:

```
1
4
3
```

But I want to make it all come to the same line , is there a way to do it without changing the main code?

```
public static void main(String[] args) 
{
    Scanner scan=new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter your number to reverse it ...");
    int a=scan.nextInt();
    while(a>0) {
        i=a%10;
        a/=10;

        l++;
        System.out.println(i);


    }
    System.out.println("Number of digits: "+l);

}
```

Comment: Use `System.out.print(...)` instead of `System.out.println(...)`.

Comment: Note that you should use `do { ... } while (a>0);`, since you always want the loop to execute (e.g. the reversal of `0` should be `0`, and it has 1 digit).

Answer (score 2):

You could use `print` instead of `println`:

```
System.out.print(i);
```

Answer (score 1):

Answer :

```
public static void main(String[] args) 
{
    Scanner scan=new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter your number to reverse it ...");
    int a=scan.nextInt();
    while(a>0) {
        i=a%10;
        a/=10;

        l++;
        System.out.print(i);


    }
    System.out.println("Number of digits: "+l);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your code has few errors. It should be

```
int i = 0;
 while(a>0) {
    i=a%10;
    a/=10;

    System.out.print(i+" ");

    i++;
 }
```

Comment: No errors at all and it works.

Comment: Thanks the issue is fixed now , it was because of println.

Answer (score 0):

In your code you are just picking digits and printing it in reversed order instead of really reversing it.

```
public static void main(String[] args) 
{
    int i,l=0,num=0;
    Scanner scan=new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter your number to reverse it ...");
    int a=scan.nextInt();
    while(a>0) 
    {
        i=a%10;
        a/=10;
        num=(num*10)+i;
        l++;


    }
    System.out.println("Number of digits: "+l);
    System.out.println("Reversed Number: "+num);
}
```

Try this code instead.....